# Background mode (fetch) in iOS 8

Tags: ios, healthkit, hockeyapp, background-fetch

I'm working on an iOS app that uses the background mode to post an update to the server. App wakes, checks the battery status, kicks off an background process and calls the completion handler. In that exact same order. And it works fine. In the iOS simulator, on my development iPhones (5s, 6 and 6 plus), but it seems to be broken on any other iPhone I've distributed the app too.

I'm currently using HockeyApp (because we're not ready to submit the app to Apple) to distribute the app. I've got the correct certificates, I've followed the background mode tutorials (for enabling it) and I'm battery friendly. Though still the background mode only works on my development iPhones and the simulator and not on any other iPhone.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Did I forget something? Did I do something wrong? Help would be appreciated, because it drives me nuts.. :(

Stefan

PS: I've included some code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/stefanvermaas/3fd27bbb270e3d1f1fbe

Comment: How can you tell it's not working? Also, are you sure the app is installing correctly? I've had signing issues distributing ipas before.

Comment: As @JackBeNimble said, this sounds like a certificate/entitlements issue. Have you monitored the console when installing and starting your app on another iOS device?

Comment: Because I don't see any new data being added to the server (which should have happened, because there is). @LukasSpieß how could I monitor the console etc? Haven't tried that before (pretty new to iOS development).

Comment: Oh and I do see new data, but it's coming from my development devices and not from the other iPhones. I'll check the certificate and entitlements again.

Comment: A quick way to check is to try to upload it to the App Store - you may get some kind of error message. Also, I believe you can access the logs through organizer - there may be an option available for the device you're attached to. I'm surprised you're not getting an error message on the install if you're doing it from Hockey Rink, though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the direction. I'll try to flush the entitlements/certificates tomorrow and make different targets. I'll keep you posted.